# How to debug docker-compose up failed?

Tags: docker

My docker configuration is returning error message with `docker-compose up`.

```
ERROR: for proxy  Container "d23a4ae03365" is unhealthy.
```

One of the containers failed to start. Now, the problem is how to debug it. Should I find the container (I know exactly which one) in my `docker-compose.yml` and build up a manual docker command like:

```
docker run -i -t <Image Name> -v ... -v ... /bin/bash
```

Go inside the container and work out why it didn't start.

That will require me manually fill in the volume paths. Otherwise, how to debug it? I just need to know the error message.

Comment: [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) will launch a container based on something in your `docker-compose.yml` file, but with an alternate command and without published ports.  That could help you get a debugging shell, at least.

Comment: So I need to manually construct a "docker run" command from my `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: No, `docker-compose run whatever-service /bin/bash` should construct an equivalent to the `docker run` command for you.